# How do I use AJAX Query in my posts loop?

Tags: loop, ajax, query

I have this function in my functions.php.

All the AJAX and Query is working but displays the results of the loop right below the AJAX filter.

I want the query loop to display in my main theme's masonry.php file instead.

Is this possible somehow? I was trying to make the $query variable global and use it elsewhere but no luck.

Cheers.

```
function misha_filter_function(){
    // $args = array(
    //     'orderby' => 'date', // we will sort posts by date
    //     'order' => $_POST['date'] // ASC or DESC
    // );

    $args = array (
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );

    if( isset( $_POST['sortby'] ) )
        switch ($_POST['sortby'])
        {
            case 'DATE_ASC':
                 $args = array(
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    'orderby' => 'date',
                    'order' => 'ASC'
                );
            break;
            case 'DATE_DESC':
                 $args = array(
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    'orderby' => 'date',
                    'order' => 'DESC'
                );
            break;
            case 'PRICE_ASC':
                 $args = array(
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    'meta_key' => 'image_price',
                    'type' => 'NUMERIC',
                    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                    'order' => 'ASC'
                );
            break;
            case 'PRICE_DESC':
                 $args = array(
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    'meta_key' => 'image_price',
                    'type' => 'NUMERIC',
                    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                    'order' => 'DESC'
                );
            break;
        }

    // for taxonomies / categories
    if( isset( $_POST['categoryfilter'] ) )
        $args['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $_POST['categoryfilter']
            )
        );

    // create $args['meta_query'] array if one of the following fields is filled
    if( isset( $_POST['price_min'] ) && $_POST['price_min'] || isset( $_POST['price_max'] ) && $_POST['price_max'] )
        $args['meta_query'] = array( 'relation'=>'AND' ); // AND means that all conditions of meta_query should be true

    // if both minimum price and maximum price are specified we will use BETWEEN comparison
    if( isset( $_POST['price_min'] ) && $_POST['price_min'] && isset( $_POST['price_max'] ) && $_POST['price_max'] ) {
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'meta_key' => 'image_price',
            'value' => array( $_POST['price_min'], $_POST['price_max'] ),
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
            'compare' => 'between'
        );
    } else {
        // if only min price is set
        if( isset( $_POST['price_min'] ) && $_POST['price_min'] )
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key' => 'image_price',
                'value' => $_POST['price_min'],
                'type' => 'NUMERIC',
                'compare' => '>'
            );

        // if only max price is set
        if( isset( $_POST['price_max'] ) && $_POST['price_max'] )
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key' => 'image_price',
                'value' => $_POST['price_max'],
                'type' => 'NUMERIC',
                'compare' => '<'
            );
    }


    // if post thumbnail is set
    if( isset( $_POST['featured_image'] ) && $_POST['featured_image'] == 'on' )
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        );

    global $query;
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    add_query_var($query);

    if( $query->have_posts() ) :
        while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
            echo '<h2>' . $query->post->post_title . '</h2>';
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    else :
        echo 'No posts found';
    endif;

    die();
}


add_action('wp_ajax_myfilter', 'misha_filter_function'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myfilter', 'misha_filter_function');
```

Comment: Also, is there a way to avoid duplicate code: 'posts_per_page' => -1,